# How to remove gap/margin from the left or right entire side of web page

Tags: html, css

this is the link to my html/css code, I have used Eric Meyer's reset for CSS and added additional code to my css in order to make my header static relevant to the entire app, but unfortunately there is a tiny margin on my entire left side of the page. Please can you help me understand what is the cause of that margin, as with Eric Meyer's reset all block elements are set to 0.
Here is the link to my code.

http://jsbin.com/tatuwe/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a character on the first line of your CSS which is causing all of the css to be ignored...

```
 * http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 2. v2.0 | 20110126
  License: none (public domain)
*/
```

should be...

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 2. v2.0 | 20110126
  License: none (public domain)
*/
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/likuhicecu/1/)

Comment: This is correct, thats why you get some "user agent stylesheet" styles on element like a default margin since nothing is defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Comment starting problem just replace below line with yours

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 2. v2.0 | 20110126
 License: none (public domain)
*/
```